Braintree Online Payments - Can you send a link to a customer to make payment
We are looking at Braintree Payments for our website,
We require the ability to be able to send a "payment link" to a customer to make a payment online on occasion.
Does Braintree payments offer this option? I cannot see it referenced on their website like Stripe for example
nothing to write here
